# Focus selected item in the list and blur background

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Focus on the item selected in a list like an app's quick actions menu.

How to create in jetpack compose a long-press in item list (lazyColumn) that focuses on the item selected and blurs the background. Also, show a quick actions menu.

Example UI

[image]